# Can i choose my own name for the output of hive queries with only one output file?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I get multiple output files of my hive queries. So, my first question is can i configure my output to be only in one file. Also, can i choose my own name of the output instead of 0000?

FYI, i am not using the jar file to submit job to hadoop. Instead of it i am using hive queries for my jobs. So, then how do i rename my output file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a single file as the output by setting the number of reducers to 0. You can do this from the Hive CLI :

```
hive>  set mapred.reduce.tasks = 1;
```

Yes, you can change the name of the output file. You can subclass the `OutputFormat.java` class and write your own. You can look at the code of TextOutputFormat.java and  MultipleOutputFormat.java etc. for reference. To do that you can just subclass that class and override the methods you need to change.

Comment: Tariq If, let's say i am not submitting my jobs as a jar to hadoop. rather i am using hive to run map reduce jobs. Then how will i use my custom java file. Reason being it will by default call the parent class.